# VBA How to find closest number

Tags: excel, vba, range, max

I have a range (which changes at certain intervals). For each change, I would like to find the numbers in the range that are closest to 0.5, both on the upside and on the downside. So, for instance, if I have:
0.42
0.48
0.51
0.53

I would like to grab 0.48 and 0.51.

Right now I have this code:

```
 Set Rng = Sheet1.Range("L" & FirstRow & ":L" & RangeCount)
 MaximumInRange = WorksheetFunction.Max(Rng)
```

I am calculating the maximum in the range, but it's pretty useless. I don't know how to grab the maximum number < 0.5 and the minimum > 0.5.

Thanks!

Comment: What should happen if all the numbers are below 0.5 or all the numbers are above 0.5? What should happen if there exists 1 or even 2 numbers which equal 0.5?

Comment: I know for sure there are numbers both below and above, and I know for sure there exists no number = 0.5

Comment: What is the delimiter between numbers? A space?

Comment: No, it's cells. It's a column of cells, each cell contains one number. As you can see, the range containing these cells is already defined in my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might help:

```
Function BestStraddle(R As Range, target As Double) As Variant
    'Returns a variant array which consists
    'of the largest value < target and
    'smallest value > target

    Dim c As Range
    Dim v As Variant, lower As Variant, upper As Variant

    For Each c In R.Cells
        v = c.Value
        If v < target Then
            If IsEmpty(lower) Then
                lower = v
            ElseIf lower < v Then
                lower = v
            End If
        ElseIf v > target Then
            If IsEmpty(upper) Then
                upper = v
            ElseIf upper > v Then
                upper = v
            End If
        End If
    Next c

    BestStraddle = Array(lower, upper)

End Function
```

With your test data in A1:A4, if I run:

```
Sub test()
    Dim A As Variant
    A = BestStraddle(Range("A1:A4"), 0.5)
    Debug.Print A(0)
    Debug.Print A(1)
End Sub
```

Then 0.48 and 0.51 are printed to the immediate window.

Comment: Thanks John, much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You just need to loop through the range, with checks to to determine if the numbers meet your criteria better than the last one:

```
Dim Cl As Range

' Arbitrarily set min and max values (maybe replace this with the min and max values of the range):
MinVal = 0
MaxVal = 100
For Each Cl In Rng
  If 0.5 - Cl < 0.5 - MinVal And Cl < 0.5 Then MinVal = Cl
  If Cl - 0.5 < MaxVal - 0.5 And Cl > 0.5 Then MaxVal = Cl
Next Cl

' Output the values however you need them:
Debug.Print MinVal
Debug.Print MaxVal
```